# XML to PDF conversion by Watson service is possible?

Tags: ibm-watson

Can we convert XML to PDF by watson Document conversion service please, I have seen the other way is possible, how to convert XML to PDF by any existing service of Bluemix/Watson?

Comment: That would be highly dependent on what kind of XML it is and how you want it printed. Do you have a stylesheet/transformation?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry - as far as I know, there are no services on Bluemix for generating PDF files.